# Как заполнить статический Dictionary делегатами на нестатические методы?

Tags: c#, ооп, словари

Имеется структура, которая является объединением, у каждого объекта есть свой метод чтения и очистки памяти за собой. Мне нужно сделать выборку делегата очистки или чтения через `Dictionary<uint, (ReadDelegate, CleanDelegate)>`.

Проблема заключается не в самих методах, а в том что они не статические, да и мне не выгодно для каждого объекта создавать список этих делегатов для чтения и чистки.

Чего я хочу добиться? Примерно такого. Но увы, методы не статические, и я не понимаю как мне один раз инициализировать этот словарь, что бы после этого пользоваться им.

```
private delegate Result ReadDelegate(Stream stream);
private delegate void CleanDelegate();

private static Dictionary<uint, (ReadDelegate, CleanDelegate)> ReadCleanMethods;
```

Структура выглядит так, как приведено ниже *(экономия памяти на выделении объектов, и сведение к минимуму кол-во выделений)*:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal partial struct Chunk
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkCommon Common;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkList List;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkIdx1 Idx1;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkAvih Avih;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkStrh Strh;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkStrf Strf;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkStrd Strd;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkVprp Vprp;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkIndx Indx;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal ChunkString String;

    private delegate Result ReadDelegate(Stream stream);
    private delegate void CleanDelegate();

    private static Dictionary<uint, (ReadDelegate, CleanDelegate)> ReadCleanMethods;
}
```

Как и когда это лучше сделать?

Comment: 1) Почему не можете сделать методы статическими? 2) Почему не можете сделать нестатическую инициализацию при старте приложения и заполнять ваш словать там?

Comment: @tym32167, эти методы работают со внутренностями структур, поэтому не могут быть статическими. А на счет второго, у меня была идея сделать заполнение словаря в статическом конструкторе, с использованием локальной переменной типа `Chunk`, но это даже звучит подозрительно, а на счет заполнения при старте приложения, я не могу сделать это из библиотеки.

Comment: то есть вы хотите хранить в статике делегаты, которые хрнят ссылки на какие то ваши структуры? У вас утечек памяти не будет? Как вы планируете этим пользоваться и управлять?

Comment: @tym32167, Утечек там не будет, а делегаты не хранят ссылки на структуры, они только вычитывают данные из переданного им `Stream`, сохраняют данные в себя, и дальше, при удалении они чистятся _(если такое необходимо)_. А управление осуществляется с помощью вдусвязного списка, который содержится в структуре `ChunkCommon`, а каждая из последующих структур в себе первым полем хранит эту структуру. Т.е. утечек не будет, функционал очистки продумал, но вот на счет заполнения ничего в голову не пришло.

Comment: `они только вычитывают данные из переданного им Stream, сохраняют данные в себя` это не понял, это как? :)

Comment: @tym32167, у каждой вложенной структуры свои методы чтения, очистки, а структура `Chunk`, служит для объединения, что бы не выделять память под разные типы структур. Короче говоря, уже сам запутался, и думаю просто написать огромный свитч.

Comment: я бы начал со switch, после накатал бы десяток другой тестов, а уже после этого пробовал бы что там оптимизировать / минимизировать

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Делегат - это объект, который указывает либо на статический метод, либо на метод экземпляра и конкретный объект, у которого он будет вызываться. Создать делегат, указывающий на метод экземпляра, без указания конкретного объекта нельзя. Возможно, вместо делегата вы имели в виду [MethodInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=netstandard-2.1), который как раз указывает на метод без привязки к конкретному экземпляру, и позволяет перейти к делегату с помощью метода CreateDelegate:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        int a;

        public void ReadA(Stream s)
        {
            a = s.ReadByte();
        }

        int b;

        public void ReadB(Stream s)
        {
            b = s.ReadByte();
        }

        public delegate void ReadDelegate(Stream stream);

        static Dictionary<uint, MethodInfo> readmethods = new Dictionary<uint, MethodInfo>();

        static MyStruct()
        {
            readmethods[0] = typeof(MyStruct).GetMethod("ReadA");
            readmethods[1] = typeof(MyStruct).GetMethod("ReadB");
        }

        public Dictionary<uint, ReadDelegate> GetReadDelegates()
        {
            var delegates = new Dictionary<uint, ReadDelegate>();

            foreach (uint key in readmethods.Keys)
            {
                delegates[key] = (ReadDelegate)readmethods[key].CreateDelegate(typeof(ReadDelegate), this);
            }

            return delegates;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Такое да, как вариант, однако но это не сработает с моей структурой, ну еще не выгодно ы итерациях получать новый словарь с делегатами. Дешевле `switch`.